# How to cusomize facebook's sharer.php to sharer images on chats and Timeline

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

Below is the code used to share an image in facebook:

```
<div><a href="#" 
  onclick="
    window.open(
      'https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?m2w&u=[[Link to share]]&mode=message', 
      'facebook-share-dialog', 
      'width=626,height=436'); 
    return false;"><img src="send.png(the image clicking on which the sharer window will open)"></a></div>
```

the above code will open the facebook sharer window in private message mode.
[image]

If we remove the  **&mode=message** after the link to share, the sharer window will say share on your timeline.
Can anyone please help me how to make the sharer window open saying 'share on a friends timeline' or 'share in a group' by default.

Comment: I don't think the sharer can do that. But you can do this with the feed dialog with the `to` field set - https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/feed/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure what you're asking for,

> If we remove the &mode=message after the link to share, the sharer
>   window will say share on your timeline. Can anyone please help me how
>   to make the sharer window open saying 'share on a friends timeline' or
>   'share in a group' by default.

anyways if you want to show the option "Share on a friend's timeline" to be shown by default add `&mode=friend` to end of share dialog and for group use `&mode=group`

```
<a id="share" href="#" data-share="https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?m2w&u=http://flatuicolors.com/&mode=group" class="groupBtn">Share in Group</a>

<a id="share" href="#" data-share="https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?m2w&u=http://flatuicolors.com/&mode=friend" class="friendBtn">Share on Friend's Timeline</a>
```

Here's an example http://jsfiddle.net/AdamAzad/Lm2sc/

Comment: &mode=page for sending it to page. Thanks for the help

Comment: The mode parameter does not work for me, even when I follow your jsfiddle. I guess facebook deprecated that feature?

Answer (score -1):

In order to "Share" via private message add
&mode=message